# wysiwyg editor which uses paragraph tags

Tags: editor, wysiwyg

I must have looked at at least 15 different editors and all of them seem to use `<br/>` tags for their line breaks. I would very much prefer to find one which wraps each return with paragraph tags.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do, the wysiwyg editor built into wordpress uses paragraph tags.

Also I've noticed that most editors use a line break for a single return, but use a paragraph tag for two returns.

Comment: Good suggestions, I will be using that one. http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php for anyone else interested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you might have searched for, but the 2 main WYSIWYG editors are [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) and tinyMCE and both of them take do generate paragraphs by default. I think than in tinyMCE you can't control it, but CKEditor allows to specify if you want to use p, br or div for enter and shift+enter.